# How to get the table data using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium

Anyone
I have data in following page
https://libgen.lc/search.php?req=Hello+Python&lg_topic=libgen&open=0&view=simple&res=25&phrase=1&column=def
How can i loop through each row and get the data using selenium and python,i have tried every method and tutorial but every attempt was un-successfull.
Please someone help me.Currently I am writing a book downloader programe for downloading a book from libgen.lc using only Author Name and Book Name.
Thank You!!!

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rows_locator = "//table[@class='c']/tbody/tr"
columns_locator = "./td"

driver.get("https://libgen.lc/search.php?req=Hello+Python&lg_topic=libgen&open=0&view=simple&res=25&phrase=1&column=def")

rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(rows_locator)
data = []
for row in rows:
    columns = row.find_elements_by_xpath(columns_locator)
    row_data = []
    for column in columns:
        row_data.append(column.text)
    data.append(row_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the Xpath method, as I find it easier. Please find the below code to get a list of dictionaries with Author and Book Name.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://libgen.lc/search.php?req=Hello+Python&lg_topic=libgen&open=0&view=simple&res=25&phrase=1&column=def"

driver.get(url)

all_rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@class="c"]/tbody/tr')
data = []    # list of dictionaries with Author and Book Name

# As the first row is table head, we iterate from 1 to get the data.
for index in range(1, len(all_rows)):
    all_columns = all_rows[index].find_elements_by_tag_name("td")
    author = all_columns[1].text
    book_name = all_columns[2].text
    data.append({
        "author": author,
        "book_name": book_name
    }) 

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I will not write the whole code for you, here's is some pseudo code:

```
# Get all rows
rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("body > table.c > tbody > tr:not(:first-child)")

# Loops through each rows
for row in rows:
    id = row.find_element_by_css_selector('> td:nth-child(1)')
    author = row.find_element_by_css_selector('> td:nth-child(2)')
    title = row.find_element_by_css_selector('> td:nth-child3)')
    ...
```

Note:

1. This page has no unique id or class for each element, so we need to use css selector
2. You can also use xpath, this still requires some css knowledge, too.